# Why doesn't PyParsinig store the generating rule name in the AST?

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, pyparsing

I assembled my first pyparsing example (I used other frameworks like Irony in before), which works quite well. An AST can be printed to the console by pretty printing.

I can't find any resource on how to store and query the rule names of AST nodes. SetName("....") has no effect.

My input documents can have 1 to 5 levels in one boolean expression, so I need to know which rule matched and generated the AST node.

I didn't post my grammar yet - it's not the shortest :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setName()` sets the name of the expression, like `integer`, so that exception messages are meaningful - it describes the expression itself, not the data that was parsed. `setResultsName()` sets the name of the parsed value so that you can access by name from the parsed results. `expr.setResultsName("abc")` can also be abbreviated as `expr("abc")`, to cut down on the ugly clutter in the grammar definition.

If you are parsing a Boolean expression, please check out the simpleBool.py example that comes with the source distribution, or available on the pyparsing wiki Examples page at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py/451074414/simpleBool.py

Comment: Is this collection of pyparsing examples a list of user examples/questions? The `setResultsName()` method works as described. Shall I upload my complex example somewhere?

Comment: A few were user-submitted, most were written by me as illustrations of some features or complex applications of pyparsing. If your code is not confidential, you can post it on pastebin.com.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing